# iterate over a list in a txt file on bash

Tags: bash

i'm trying to build a bash command in order to run command over each element on my list in order to delete a list of files from s3.

I have got a file with a list:
["myfolder/myfile1.txt","myimages/myfile2.txt","blob/myfile2.txt"]

I want to to take each file location
and run the aws rm command on it.
but the comma and the " is interpating i geuss. and its not working at all.

**aws s3 rm s3://bucket-name/myimages/myfile2.txt**

I have tried:

```
for i in mytxtfile.txt
 do
 {
   aws s3 rm s3://bucket-name/"$i"
 }
done
```

can I get some help ?

Comment: Assuming the filenames in the list don't contain either a comma or a square bracket: Remove the brackets (not the commas) using `tr`, which gives you a string of filenames separated by comma. Split this string on the commas (for instance by setting IFS and use word splitting), which gives you the individual pieces you can iterate over.

Comment: Your loop body is executed exactly once, with `i` set to the string `mytxtfile.txt`. Hence you are executing `aws s3 rm s3://bucket-name/mytxtfile.txt`.

Comment: @user1934428 can you give me exmaple on how to split on the commas after removing the brackets?

Comment: Something like. `IFS=,; for i in $my_string; ....`. But here on [so], it is custom that you ask such a concrete problem in a separate question, instead of discussing it in a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
for i in $(cat mytxtfile.txt | tr -d '[]"' | tr , '\n'); do
   aws s3 rm s3://bucket-name/"$i"
done
```

This echoes the content of `mytxtfile.txt` on three lines, deleting the brackets and quotes, and replacing the comma by a line break.

Attention: if the file names and paths contain spaces, commas, square brackets, etc..., we will have to recode more carefully.

Comment: Curly braces can be removed.

Comment: @IlyaSher: correct. I inherited these redundant brackets from the code of the PO. I will remove these.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while read fname;do
    aws s3 rm "s3://bucket-name/$fname"
done <mytxtfile.txt
```

`for VAR in SOMETHING` expects `SOMETHING` to be a list. In your case `mytxtfile.txt` is interpreted as a list with single item, `mytxtfile.txt`

Edit: previous solution assumed one item per line. If the file contains valid JSON (array at the top level):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cat mytxtfile.txt | jq -r '.[]' | while read fname;do
    aws s3 rm "s3://bucket-name/$fname"
done
```

Comment: its not itertain on the file names.
its just use the all file and not 1 by 1

Comment: I assumed it was one item per line but now rereading your question: does your file contain a valid JSON (array)?

Answer (score -3):

read the file with the IFS as the comma, with the use of curly brackets for example,

```
while IFS=, read i;do
    aws s3 rm s3://bucket-name/"${i}"
done < mytxtfile.txt
```

The speech marks would allow for the variable to be expanded.

This webpage explains really well about variables and substitution, when to use speech marks, or to use a quote and more, have a read, http://www.compciv.org/topics/bash/variables-and-substitution/

Comment: There are well defined rules for bash to recognize the end of a variable name. The closing quote would be one of those characters signalling the end.